# Creating a currency converter in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator, currency

Created the UI which works fine (not my own code followed a guy on youtube)
can't seem to get the currency to convert. keeps saying:

```
str object is not callable.
```

FYI, I know nothing about python or have any experience. This is a college project.
where am I going wrong?
thanks in advance

```
DateofOrder = StringVar()
value0 = StringVar()
convert = DoubleVar()
currency = DoubleVar()


def ConCurrency():
   if value0.get() == "USA":
    convert1 = float (convert.get() * 1.52)
    convert2 = "USA Dollars", str('£.2f' '£'(convert1)) 
    currency.set(convert2)
   elif value0.get() == "Kenya":
    convert1 = float(convert.get() * 156.21)
    convert2 = "Kemyan Shilling", str('£.2f' '£'(convert1)) 
    currency.set(convert2)
   elif value0.get() == "Brazil":
    convert1 = float(convert.get() * 5.86)
    convert2 = "Brazilian Real", str('£.2f' '£'(convert1)) 
    currency.set(convert2)
   elif value0.get() == "Canada":
    convert1 = float(convert.get() * 2.03)
    convert2 = "Canadian Dollar", str('£.2f' '£'(convert1)) 
    currency.set(convert2)
   elif value0.get() == "India":
    convert1 = float(convert.get() * 101.71)
    convert2 = "Indian Rupee", str('£.2f' '£'(convert1)) 
    currency.set(convert2)
   elif value0.get() == "Phillappines":
    convert1 = float(convert.get() * 71.74)
    convert2 = "Philipine Peso", str('£.2f' '£'(convert1)) 
    currency.set(convert2)
```

Comment: Can you show us the `StringVar` and `DoubleVar` functions please?

Comment: I didn't indent it properly on here if that's one of your issues. Thanks for the help Rogan, Always appreciate the positivity. Harrison, i'm being honest in saying i'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @Harrison: Seems likely that they're from [tkinter](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm), but we can't really tell.

Comment: yes I am using tkinter

Comment: from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, ttk

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing and I'm not claiming I know anything, just any help would be appreciated

Comment: I wasn't trying to be critical of your efforts, it's more the tutorial you're learning from and then I found in later comments that you're using ttkinter so it's probable I don't recognise the structure of the code. This is quite different to how you would structure most python code.

Comment: What do you think (or hope) something like `'£'(convert1)` will do?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say so, but I am guessing that the message `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` occurs at this line:

```
convert2 = "USA Dollars", str('£.2f' '£'(convert1))
```

(or one of the several that look like it). To get rid of the error, fix your assignment statement:

```
convert2 = "USA Dollars", str('£%.2f' % convert1)
```

or better, since it is simpler and equivalent:

```
convert2 = "USA Dollars", '£%.2f' % convert1
```

That will result in `convert2` looking something like this:

```
('USA Dollars', '£1.33')
```

The trouble with that is `currency` is a Tkinter `DoubleVar` and its `set` method is not expecting a tuple of two strings: it's expecting a float, something like `1.33` (a number, without the quotes and the GBP sign). So fixing the assignment will just move your problem.

Can I suggest that you begin by getting the basic currency conversion logic working in a simple, if unfriendly, console program first, and regard the Tkinter implementation as phase 2?